# SAS creating batch files

Tags: batch-file, sas

I am having trouble trying to figure out why my .bat file wont work. So far this is what I have:

@ECHO OFF

"C:\Program Stuff\Home\SASEnterpriseGuide\7.1\SEGuide.exe" -sysin "C:\Test\Daily report.sas"

PAUSE

It opens SAS just fine and then when it goes to import the sas file it gives me an error the error is a Text File Access Error.

I dont know if their is an easier way of doing this but I would like for it to open SAS like it is doing and then run that sas file. Any help would be appreciated. Also a side note I am using sas 7.1 64bit.

Answer (score 2):

Running SAS in batch mode is meant to be done with `sas.exe`, not Enterprise Guide:

```
"C:\Program Stuff\Home\SASFoundation\9.X\sas.exe" -sysin "C:\Test\Daily report.sas"
```

If you abolutely need to use EGuide to run your program, you can go to `File->Schedule...`. This generates a VBS script that is used by Windows Task Scheduler to execute your scheduled project but you could call that script from your batch job.

Comment: If I have sas installed will I automatically have sas.exe? when I type that in it doesnt come up with anything

Comment: No, you may not have SAS installed, especially if SAS EG is connecting to a server and not locally. If this is the case, talk to your IT team on how to automate/schedule a job.